# Forward and Futures Contracts and Arbitrage Profit

Tags: finance

Is it possible to make an arbitrage profit by taking a long position in the futures contract and a short position in the forward contract when Forward Contract F(0,0) > Futures Contract G(0,0)? That is, the forward contract and futures contract at time = 0 and state = 0.

Edit 1: I believe it has to do with the fact that under the No-Arbitrage Axiom,  we must have that F(N,j) = S(N,j) (foward price equal to asset price) and G(N,j) = S(N,j) (futures price equal to asset price).

Comment: This may be more appropriate for Quantitative Finance StackExchange.

Comment: @RRL thank you for the tip. I'll redirect the question.